# Basic Login with SESSIONS

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I'm having issues with a simple login using php and mysql.

Here is my code:

LOGIN.PHP

```
 <?php

    //include 'core/init.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    //JH check if user is logged in already
    if (loggedin()) {
        header("location: userarea.php");
        exit();
    }

    if ($_POST['login']) { 
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $remember = $_POST['remember'];
        $password_encrip = hash('md5', $pass);

    if ($user&&$pass) {
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user'");
        while  ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login))   
        $db_pass = $row['pass']; {

        if ($password_encrip==$db_pass) 
            $login_ok = TRUE;
        else 
            $login_ok = FALSE;
        }

        if ($login_ok==TRUE) {

            if ($remember=="on")
                setcookie("user", $user, time()+7200);

            else if ($remember=="")
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;

            header("Location: userarea.php");
            exit();

        } else 
            echo "ERROR: Username/Password combination incorrect!";

        } else 
            die("ERROR: Hit back and enter username and password!");
    }


    ?>

    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <b style="font-size:150%;">Log in</b><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" />Remember me<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in"/>
    </form>
```

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
  <?php 

    // REPORT ERRORS?
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // SESSIONS CHECK
    session_start();

    //CONNECT TO DATABASE/CONNECT
    mysql_connect("localhost","MYSQL","PASS") or die();
    mysql_select_db('DB') or die();

    // LOGIN CHECK FUNCTION
    function loggedin()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['$user']) || isset($_COOKIE['$user']))
        {
            $loggedin = TRUE;
            return $loggedin;
        }
    }


    ?>
```

USERAREA.PHP

```
        <?php 

    //include 'core/init.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    //JH check if user is logged in already
    if (!loggedin())
    {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    ?>

    <p>Welcome! You're Logged in</p> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/>


    <?php
        echo "Welcome SESS: ".$_SESSION['user']. "<br/>";
        echo "Welcome Cookie: ".$_COOKIE['user']. "<br/>";
    ?>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: TOTZBALLS??  really... TOTZBALLS???

Comment: Basically it forwards me to userarea.php but that kicks me back to login.php and then also I get Bad password/combination error.

Comment: Yeh!!! **TOTZBALLS AMAZEBALLZ! **

Comment: Somebody is gonna come and say it, so it might as well be me.  Consider a framework - Kohana, CodeIgniter, CakePHP and Symphony all have great alternatives to rolling your own for auth structures.  If this is an exercise then I suppose there is no need, but if it is intended to be deployed in a functional sense you'll save so many headaches.

Comment: Looks like a SQL injection risk...

Comment: I appreciate your input - Deacon & Ken.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the PHP, put `session_start();` (the first page you have posted).

Comment: Thanks for the input, Im sure this wouldnt make any difference as its being added to session via functions.php? Added it anyway!

Ive taken off the MD5 pass encryption and it is now setting the SESSION/COOKIE but only refreshing the page and not sending me to userarea.php and echoing SESSION and COOKIE = 'admin' as it should.

Very strange, can anyone test this?

Comment: OOPS, in the functions.php the loggedin function was not correct, 'if (isset($_SESSION['$user']) || isset($_COOKIE['$user']))' - Deleted $ and works fine. Sorry!

Comment: I would have never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot one big thing is you always want to sanitize user inputs before there added to queries and also if $_post values are not set they don't return false so doing if($_POST['something']) would return an error

```
----------------------------------- LOGIN.PHP



<?php

    //include 'core/init.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    //JH check if user is logged in already
    if (loggedin()) {
        header("location: userarea.php");
        exit();
    }

    if ($_POST['login']) {
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $remember = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remember']);
        $password_encrip = hash('md5', $pass);

        if (!empty($user) && !empty($pass)) {
            $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pass = '$password_encrip'");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)) {

                if (count($row) > 0) {
                    $login_ok = TRUE;
                } else {
                    $login_ok = FALSE;
                }
            }

            if ($login_ok) {

                if ($remember == "on") {
                    setcookie("user", $user, time() + 7200);
                } else if ($remember == "") $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

                header("Location: userarea.php");
                exit();

            } else {
                echo "ERROR: Username/Password combination incorrect!";
            }

        } else {
            die("ERROR: Hit back and enter username and password!");
        }
    }


?>

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <b style="font-size:150%;">Log in</b><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"/>Remember me<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in"/>
</form>


------------------------------------------ FUNCTIONS.PHP

<?php

    // REPORT ERRORS?
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // SESSIONS CHECK
    session_start();

    //CONNECT TO DATABASE/CONNECT
    mysql_connect("localhost", "MYSQL", "PASS") or die();
    mysql_select_db('DB') or die();

    // LOGIN CHECK FUNCTION
    function loggedin() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['$user']) || isset($_COOKIE['$user'])) {
            $loggedin = TRUE;
            return $loggedin;
        }
    }


?>






---------------------------------------------- USERAREA.PHP



<?php

    //include 'core/init.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    //JH check if user is logged in already
    if (!loggedin()) {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

?>

<p>Welcome! You're Logged in</p> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/>


<?php
    echo "Welcome SESS: " . $_SESSION['user'] . "<br/>";
    echo "Welcome Cookie: " . $_COOKIE['user'] . "<br/>";
?>
```